# How to resize ion-spinner

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using `ion-spinner` in a ionic application. But im my case i want to change the size of the spinner. When i use custom css with default spinner Resizing works fine. But with Bubbles,Circles, Dots spinners, it doesn't work properly.
**CSS**

```css
.spinner-large {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
    <ion-spinner name="dots" class="spinner-large"></ion-spinner>
```

how can i fix this.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xdwslp)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using

```
ion-spinner {
    transform: scale(3);
}
```

From ionic forum its mentioned that this will make you loose some resolution.

Comment: This approach is just brilliant. It can be applied any Ionic Component. Very good!

Answer (score 6):

As Ionic 4, you can use width & height:

```css
ion-spinner {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
}
```

> https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/18115

Comment: Worked for me ✅. In my case, I needed to make the spinner smaller.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar styling issue and to resolve it I needed to add
`position: absolute` to css rules